# UITableView still present after calling removeFromSuperView()

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a search bar in a view controller that once the user clicks enter, it pulls the search data from an API and initializes a `tableview` with the data.

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

    setupTableView()

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {

        self.searchLabel.removeFromSuperview()
        self.searchBar.center = CGPoint(x: self.searchBar.frame.midX, y: 40)
        self.tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 25 + searchBar.frame.size.height, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height - (25 + searchBar.frame.height) - (self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.size.height)!)

    })

    searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(true, animated: true)
}
```

Here is the `setupTableView()` function:

```
func setupTableView() {

    tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 44 + searchLabel.frame.height + searchBar.frame.size.height, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height - (44 + searchLabel.frame.height + searchBar.frame.size.height) - (self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.size.height)!))
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.register(SearchCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "TableViewCell")
    frame = tableView.frame
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    view.addSubview(tableView)

}
```

Now here is the function that is called when the user clicks **Cancel** next to the search bar.

```
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

    searchBar.text = ""
    searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: true)
    searchBar.endEditing(true)
    self.tableView.removeFromSuperview()
    view.addSubview(searchLabel)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {

        searchBar.center = self.center

    })
}
```

All the code in this function works, except the

```
self.tableView.removeFromSuperView()
```

The tableview is still visible and clickable by the user. I have also tried using the hide function, but that does not work either. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `setupTableView` called only once?

Comment: as @Larme suggested, maybe setupTableView is called after.

some additional suggestions:

- make sure you are performing UI operations on the main thread (usually a cause for similar problems)

- call view.setNeedsLayout() view.layoutIfNeeded()

Comment: @AndreiDurnea how do I make sure I'm performing UI operations on the main thread? Do I simply call those functions which you suggested? Sorry, I'm pretty new to this

Comment: @Larme the function is only called once, in the first function presented above

Comment: You can print something in the `setupTableView()` to make sure it's not adding more than 1 table (as suggested above). And you can iterate through all subviews (`for view in self.view.subviews`) and simply check it.

Comment: @tjc did you validate that through using breakpoints? you should place a breakpoint at where it gets removed and and place another at where it gets added to the view hierarchy. If it reaches addSubview again after you remove it then you do have a problem...

Comment: After self.tableView.removeFromSuperView() call, setting nil value for your table view might help like self.tableView = nil.

Comment: @NareshReddyM that would work, but he needs to get to the root of his problem.

Comment: @bauerMusic you found this issue! For some reason, there is more than one tableview being initiated. However, I have more than just the tableview on the view controller, so doing that removes ALL subviews. In the for statement, how can I determine if a view is of type tableview?

Comment: @tjc No. Don't. Fix the issue about "Why there is multiple tableView" instead.

Comment: Like @Larme said, you should fix it where the 'extra' table is added. I did not suggest removing all subviews, that was only to check what views were added. The answer by Kevinosaurio should do it (although, I'd drop the `tableView.isDescendant` part), unless you have another table somewhere. Just initialize inside the `if tableView == nil` block.

Answer (score 1):

You init the tableView several times, you need to check if the tableView is nil first. Try with this:

```
func setupTableView() {

    if tableView == nil
    {
       tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 44 + searchLabel.frame.height + searchBar.frame.size.height, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height - (44 + searchLabel.frame.height + searchBar.frame.size.height) - (self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.size.height)!))
       tableView.delegate = self
       tableView.dataSource = self
       tableView.register(SearchCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "TableViewCell")
       frame = tableView.frame
       tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    }

    if(!tableView.isDescendant(of: view)) {
       self.view.addSubview(tableView)
    }
}
```